# Getting accurate vehicle speed

Tags: android

I want to get accurate vehicle speed through GPS without using internet or mobile data in Android. Is it possible to get accurate vehicle speed when mobile data and wifi are off but the GPS is ON?

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any attempts made?

Comment: I am using alarm manager for 30 seconds. On every 30 second I am calling LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates. When I get response on onLocationChanged, I store current location on shared pref, Also I am using distanceTo method to get distance between current location and previous shared pref location then using distance formula to get speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes.

> Is it acurate?

Depends on what you define as acurate. But I would say rather not.

#### Approach

`location.getSpeed()`

Check this out: [Determining the speed of a vehicle using GPS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570542/determining-the-speed-of-a-vehicle-using-gps-in-android)

Comment: location.getSpeed() always return 0.0

Comment: You are doing the calculation manual by now. This seems to work. Is too inaccurate for you? There are some tweaks in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies

Comment: Actually I am not getting accurate location by using GPS and without using wifi and mobile data.

Comment: This should be possible. If you share your code (in your question) someone can have a look into it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask